# Second & third to last value from table with condition - Excel

Tags: excel

This command to get the last digit/value of the Excel column with the condition.
=LOOKUP(2,1/(E9:E2612=D19),F9:F2612)

Same way looking for 2nd Last and 3rd Last digit/value from the excel

Comment: Try this one, `=INDEX(F9:F2612,LARGE(IF((E9:E2612<>"")*(E9:E2612=D19),ROW(E9:E2612)),{2,3}))` this gives Column Wise, while for Row Wise change {2,3} to {2;3} may need to press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` based on Excel version

Comment: The correct value is not showing. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of the data you are using with the expected output as highlighted please

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365, try:

```
=LET(arr,FILTER(F9:F2612,E9:E2612=D19),rws,ROWS(arr),INDEX(arr,SEQUENCE(3,,rws,-1)))
```

which will return a vertical array of the last three matching values.